# How to go about making an image move up in the div on hover

Tags: javascript, css, html

I have a question on how to go about making a div that when you hover it, an image on the inside will move up into the div.

This is my code so far:

```
<div id="div1">
  <div id="div2">
    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/300x300/000/fff" width="300px" height="300px">
  </div>
</div>
```

css

```
#div1 { 
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    border: 2px black solid;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    left: 500px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#div2 img {
    position: absolute;
    top:200px;
}
```

This image that sits in the div1 sits at the bottom of the div, the rest of the overflow is hidden. I want it to move up when the div is hovered.

Any idea on how to go about this? I was going to use the transform css and translateY it but I'm not sure if there is a better way that this can be done through JQuery.

Let me know what you think

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is pure css approach with transition on `hover`

```css
#div1 {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 2px black solid;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#div2 img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
}
#div1:hover img {
  top: 30%;
}
```

```html
<div id="div1">
  <div id="div2">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you Nenad, this seems like the path that I was on I just didnt know if it was the correct 1. Thanks for you help!

Answer (score 1):

```
#div1:hover #div2 img{
    top: 100px; //change this number to get correct placement
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use :hover on your CSS and specify a new location for the image when you hover.  You can even animate it so it "glides" into position.

Answer (score 1):

You have the image unnecessarily wrapped in a div. just assign the id to the image itself

```
  <div id="div1">
        <img id="div2" src="http://www.maceire.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/grey- bac  kground-1-wide-hd-background-and-wallpaper.jpg" width="300px" height="300px">
  </div>
```

Then you can manipulate to top css value

```
var q = document.getElementById('div2');
q.style.top = '0px';
```

and

```
q.style.top = '200px';
```

to move up and down

Comment: Thank you for the JS approach, I will keep this in mind.

Answer (score 1):

For performance and simplicity, use CSS if possible and resort to javascript when you need to support legacy browsers. Your needs here could easily be solved using just CSS:

```
#div1 { width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    border: 2px black solid;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    left: 500px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#div2 img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 80%;
    transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: all 2s ease-in-out; /** Chrome & Safari **/
    -moz-transition: all 2s ease-in-out; /** Firefox **/
    -o-transition: all 2s ease-in-out; /** Opera **/
}

#div1:hover #div2 img {
    top: 0%;
}
```

This approach does not require you to know the dimensions of the image.